# What is the regex expression for removing pinned versions from a Pipfile?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pipenv, vscodevim

Per the [Pipenv documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/pipfile/#importing-from-requirements-txt), when importing from a `requirements.txt` file with

```bash
pipenv install -r path/to/requirements.txt
```

it is recommended that

> if your requirements file has version numbers pinned, you’ll likely want to edit the new `Pipfile` to remove those, and let `pipenv` keep track of pinning.

### What regex to use when replacing these pinned version numbers after running `pipenv install -r path/to/requirements.txt`?

Since I prefer to use the vim search and replace command `:%s/foo/bar`, please structure your answer such that `foo` is replaced by `bar`, as above in `vim`, if possible. I mainly use vim keybindings in Visual Studio Code, so javascript-based regex is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex worked to solve this problem: `"==([\S]+)"`.

Use it via the Visual Studio Code Vim extension (and replace with a `"*"`):

```
:%s/"==([\S]+)"/"*"
```

or without the `"*"` (replacing with nothing):

```
:%s/"==([\S]+)"/
```

I used [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to assist and learn the underlying regex above.